# I have a variable varLocationRegion and i have stored whole xml. Now i want to loop through that variable in xslt

Tags: loops, variables, xslt, pass-through

I have a variable varLocationRegion and i have stored whole xml (with two elements location & region in that. Now i want to loop through that variable in xslt by matching location to get the value of region. Please advise. Thanks!

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Location_ID>111</wd:Location_ID>
        <wd:Region_Ref_ID>UNITED_STATES_REGION</wd:Region_Ref_ID>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Location_ID>111V</wd:Location_ID>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

Comment: Please [indent code by four spaces](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and show beautified, tidy XML (I've done that for you). Also, add your XSLT stylesheet to the question, together with the output you expect.

Comment: can you post what output you are expecting???

Answer (score 0):

Based on what information you have provided you can try out the following:
Solution for XSLT 1.0 can be tried in the following way:
Use Muenchian Grouping to group together unique Location_ID in your xml and the iterate upon the original xml using the unique Location_ID already available to find the list of associated Region_Ref_ID to particular a Location_ID.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:key name="uniqueLocation" match="wd:Report_Entry" use="wd:Location_ID"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!--variable called data is the variable that contains your xml-->
    <xsl:variable name="uniqueLocationData" select="$data/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry[count(.|key('uniqueLocation',wd:Location_ID)[1])=1]"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$data/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Region_Ref_ID[$data/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Location_ID=$uniqueLocationData/wd:Location_ID]">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```